# Decomposition of induced representations in S_n

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let C be a cyclic subgroup of S_n.
How does the representation $Ind_C^{S_n}\rho$, where $\rho$ is some representation of $C$, decompose into irreducible components? 
Is there are a way to know which components appear with multiplicity 1?

Comment: There are two formulas in *Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials* that might be useful, which give you the character of the induced representation written in the basis of power sums. The case where C is generated by an n-cycle and the representation is faithful appears as Exercise 7.12, and the case of C an arbitrary subgroup and the representation is trivial is Exercise 7.4.

Comment: If you just care about multiplicities, you might want to consider restrictions instead of inductions (Frobenius equivalence).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a combinatorial way to decompose $Res_C^{S_n}S^\lambda$ for an irreducible $S_n$-module $S^\lambda$. We use the notion of the "major index" for a standard tabuleau of shape $\lambda$. If $C=C_n$, the result is obtained by [Kraśkiewiz-Weyman](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=JOUR&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Weyman&s5=Coxeter&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq). See also [Garsia's paper "Combinatorics of the free Lie algebra and the symmetric group"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1039352&loc=fromreflist)(Theorem 8.4) and [Reutenauer's book "Free Lie algebras"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1231799&loc=fromreflist)(Theorem 8.8 and 8.9). This result can be generalized to any cyclic subgroup in [Jöllenbeck-Schocker's paper "Cyclic characters of symmetric groups"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=JOUR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=cyclic%20character&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=1801229).